# Bypass windows authentication when user is logged in IIS

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have created an application in IIS 7.5. For security reasons i have disabled Anonymous authentication and enabled Windows Authentication. Now, is there a way to bypass the alert box to enter windows login credentials when accessing the page assuming that the user is already logged in?

My application is written in PHP.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are being prompted to enter your credentials after enabling windows auth, it means you haven't configured it correctly. I am assuming the user who is trying to access the application is part of the same domain as that of the server. There are multiple things that you need to take care of in order to configure windows auth (SPN's, application pool identity, etc). Few questions here -

1. How do you access the web application? Do you use a custom hostname or you use the server name in the URL ?
2. Is the client machine part of the same domain as that of the server?
3. What identity is the application pool running under ?
4. Is this a load balanced environment ?